# How to sort one array based on the values of other array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am a newbie in Java. I am trying to sort array arr[] according to the values of array val[] and it should maintain the insertion order.

```
int arr[] = {2,3,2,4,5,12,2,3,3,3,12};
int val[] = {3,4,3,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,2};
```

I am using this :

```
ArrayList <Integer> al = new ArrayList <Integer> () ;
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
al.add(arr);
Collections.sort(al , (left , right) -> val[al.indexOf(left)]  -
val[al.indexOf(right)])
```

My output should be

```
4 5 12 12 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: Not sure to understand how is used second array ?

Comment: don't use parallel arrays. instead, create a class with two fields and spin up however many objects required, store it into some list  or array then sort it by a given property.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: @SalmanKhurshid has a lot of homework today

Comment: See the technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48586898/823393).

Comment: Explain your logic, how did you get 12 as the third and fourth numbers in your output

Comment: If you want to group data, create classes instead. Create a class that holds a value from both arrays. Then create a `List<Data>` over those objects and sort that using a `Comparator` or `compareTo` which compares by the first value.

Comment: You are using `indexOf`, this means that `arr=[1 1 2], val=[3 1 2]` would be sorted as `[2 1 1]` (the second `1` is using the value of the first `1`) Is this intentional? Or should it be `[1 2 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two arrays are different lengths so this fails but if you fix that problem this should work:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<Integer> getSortOrder(List<T> list) {
    // Ints in increasing order from 0. One for each entry in the list.
    List<Integer> order = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, list.size() - 1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(order, (o1, o2) -> {
        // Comparing the contents of the list at the position of the integer.
        return list.get(o1).compareTo(list.get(o2));
    });
    return order;
}

// Array form.
static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<Integer> getSortOrder(T[] list) {
    return getSortOrder(Arrays.asList(list));
}

static <T> List<T> reorder(List<T> list, List<Integer> order) {
    return order.stream().map(i -> list.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// Array form.
static <T> T[] reorder(T[] list, List<Integer> order) {
    return reorder(Arrays.asList(list), order).toArray(list);
}


public void test(String[] args) {
    Integer arr[] = {2,3,2,4,5,12,2,3,3,3,12};
    Integer val[] = {3,4,3,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,2};
    List<Integer> sortOrder = getSortOrder(val);
    Integer[] reordered = reorder(arr, sortOrder);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reordered));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `val` array seems to be one element longer.

```
    int[] arr = {2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 12};
    int[] val = {3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, /*4,*/ 2};
    int[] sortedArr = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> new int[] {arr[i], val[i]})
            .sorted((lhs, rhs) -> Integer.compare(lhs[1], rhs[1]))
            .mapToInt(pair -> pair[0])
            .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArr));
```

which results in

```
[4, 5, 12, 2, 12, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

As sorting is stable, one could either do two sorts or combine them:

```
    int[] sortedArr = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> new int[] {arr[i], val[i]})
            .sorted((lhs, rhs) -> Integer.compare(lhs[0], rhs[0]))
            .sorted((lhs, rhs) -> Integer.compare(lhs[1], rhs[1]))
            .mapToInt(pair -> pair[0])
            .toArray();
```

and then, voila

```
[4, 5, 2, 12, 12, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post, but I'd use `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(t -> t[0]))`

Comment: Also, not sure that the second code is supposed to do. I understand that OP wants the sort to be stable, you your first result would be correct.

Comment: What is the complexity of this algorithm in terms of n where n is length of array ?

Comment: @tobias_k the second does an Comparing.andThen to have the order the OP expects. That is dubious, but the formulation of the expected sorting might have been misleading. Your suggested usage of Comparator is much better.

Comment: @SalmanKhurshid after 12 was 2 with a 3 below, also an array with different values.

Comment: Well, it's still not exactly what OP's expected output looks like. The `2` should come after the 12. Seems like OP's expected output is actually using `indexOf`, i.e. not using corresponding values, but the corresponding value to the first occurrence of each number.

Comment: not sure how OP is sorting, he still hasn't explained his sorting logic

Comment: @LeBronJames At least the other array should be involved. Hence the added variant.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your sorting algorithm of choice, compare values from `val` and sort both `arr` and `val` accordingly.

Solely for the sake of brevity, here's an example using bubble-sort:

```
static void sortByVal(int[] arr, int[] val) {

    if (arr.length != val.length) { return; }        

    for (int i=0; i < val.length; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j < (val.length-i); j++) {
            if (val[j-1] > val[j]) {

                int temp = val[j-1];  
                val[j-1] = val[j];  
                val[j] = temp;

                temp = arr[j-1];  
                arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }  
    }  
}
```

Note however that you usually shouldn't resort to reimplementing a sorting algorithm but rather switch to appropriate datastructures.

For instance instead of using a key-array and a values-array, use an array containing key-value pairs. This array can then be sorted easily:

```
Collections.sort(array, (p0, p1) -> Integer.compare(p0.val, p1.val));
```

Comment: I needed solution in o(nlogn) time.

Comment: Try to learn from my example and implement the same utilizing quicksort (which performs in O(n*log(n)) time on average).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at your logic

val[0] = arr[3] = 4
val[1] = arr[4] = 5

val[2] = arr[3] the value is 4 following your current pattern.

To get 12 the desired value you would have to remove the previously used 4,5

This pattern contradicts what was done at val[1] because 4 was not removed.

Comment: This is wrong, try to look at the numbers vertically, note how 1 corresponds to 4 and 1 corresponds to 5, then 12 corresponds to 2, etc. That's the pattern